# Initialising an object with dynamic name - coffeescript/node.js/javaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I am attempting to build a plugin system where I do not know the plugins beforehand. Initialising an object using 'require' from browserify. As follows:

```
class.coffee:

   class MyClass
    name: "my-class"
    constructor: ->

    @getName: ->
        return @name

  exports.plugin = new MyClass
```

Then from the calling file I have:

```
pluginName = # from a config file
{ plugin } = require './#{pluginName}.coffee'
console.log plugin
console.log plugin.getName()
```

The first logger call gives me:

```
MyClass{ name="my-class" }
```

The second one fails however with plugin.getName is not a function.

Any help/guidance appreciated. I'm not a JS developer and am new to coffeescript/node.js as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have the `@` before `getName`.

Having the `@` is equivalent to this in JS

```
MyClass.getName = function(){
  return this.name;
};
```

But in this case, `getName` is a function on the class itself, not the MyClass instance.

Without the `@`, like this, `getName: ->` the JS is like this:

```
MyClass.prototype.getName = function(){
  return this.name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd been playing around with that and obviously left it the wrong way around. I've marked your answer as accepted answer, thanks.